# Remove String Before Json Response Body Php

Tags: php, json

Hi I am using WHMCS Api I am getting a response in json format like this

```
string 'userhowhigh83{"result":"success","orderid":787,"productids":"785","addonids":"","domainids":"","invoiceid":"766"}' (length=113)
```

I am getting the response correctly from API but it is also giving me the string 'userhowhigh83' where 'howhigh83' is the username and 'user' is given static but when I decode the json result it gives me null. I checked in on an online json decoder when I remove 'userhowhigh83' it will works fine.How can I remove this before json response body.

Comment: it's not valid json if it has unquoted string in the beginning and json_decode returns null if it fails. Check this function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php to see if error happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot get the string in better shape from your API, you always can use substring on your string to get rid of "userhowhigh83" :

```
$string = substr($string , strpos($string , "{"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do as well:

```
list($username, $jsonData) = explode('{', $json);
echo '{' . $jsonData;
echo $username;
```

Another approach will be:

```
preg_match('/{.*?}/', $json, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

Comment: Problem of your first approach is that for a bigger stringified JSON object, you could have more than one "{". But for this string it's allright :-)